# Access css class selector inside html document inside the app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've got this piece of HTML:

```
<html>
  ...
  <iframe>
    #document
    <html>
      ...
      <div className='change-me'></div>
      ...
    </html>
  </iframe>
</html>
```

That iframe is taken from stripe React element, I want to access something inside it and change its CSS.

I've dealt before with libraries that offer reusable React components, and managed easily to change every CSS detail there.

**Problem**: But here I can change nothing.

```
.change-me { background: red } // This one doesn't work
```

Maybe it's the fact that the component is making it's own html document, maybe I'm looking at the problem from the wrong end...

Comment: if it's an iframe than you cannot

Answer (score 1):

Plain CSS is not going to work. You need to change the class of the element with your own class programmatically using JavaScript and the iFrame must contain the CSS file/styling containing that class

For example, you can add your CSS file to the iframe like this:

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById("youriFrameId");
var head = iFrame.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'path/to/cssFile.css';

head.appendChild(link);
```

and then add your class to your target element like this:

```
iFrame.getElementById('targetElementId').classList.add("yourClass");
```